# Setting UIViewController view property after the view is loaded

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am building an application that requires reloading the view to display different type of question.

I have the QuestionView in place, so every time the users reload I will create a new QuestionView and change the self.view to the new view.

If I do everything on the main queue then it will work.

The view will change after I do self.view = newView:

```
//This will work. The UI will be change to the new view
[ProgressHUD show:@"Loading question"];
QuestionView *newQuestionView = [self getQuestionView]; //a time wasting task
self.view = newQuestionView;
[ProgresHUD dismiss];
```

However, this doesn't change the UI:

```
//not sure why these code won't update the UI
[ProgressHUD show:@"Loading question"];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
     QuestionView *newQuestionView = [self getQuestionView]; //a time wasting task
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
         [ProgressHUD dismiss];
         self.view = newQuestionView;
     });
});
```

I would definitely prefer the second approach. Any idea explicitly ask the controller to redraw the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The heart of your problem is that assigning to self.view both doesn't add your view to the window and is generally speaking a bad idea anyway.

Instead don't try to replace the viewcontroller's view, put your view inside self.view.

```
[questionView removeFromSuoerview];

// setup new question view here

questionView.frame = self.view.bounds;
[self.view addSubview:questionView];
```

Alternatively, you could use `transitionFromView:toView:duration:options:completion:` to transition from the old question to the new question with some nice transition animations.

Comment: But any idea why the first code works and the second one doesn't?

Comment: It will work in loadViews or in viewDidLoad because they haven't yet been added to the windows view hierarchy, so the "right" view gets added to the hierarchy.  Doing it after that it won't work because assigning to self.view does not, in and of itself, add the view to the window's view hierarchy.